# What is the difference between $VARIABLE and ${VARIABLE}

Tags: linux, bash, variables

Can anyone please provide me an explanation as to why some Linux expert suggest that we use ${VARIABLE} in Bash scripts? There doesn't seem to be any difference at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say you want to print `$VARIABLE` immediately followed by `"string"`

```
echo "$VARIABLEstring"    # tries to print the variable called VARIABLEstring
echo "${VARIABLE}string"  # prints $VARIABLE and then "string"
```

Bash also supports [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) using this syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other differences ?

Comment: @爱国者 no, there are not any other differences.

Comment: The `${}` form is also essential when dereferencing arrays. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html for more details.

Answer (score 5):

One reason you may want to do this is `{}` act as delimiters:

```
a=42
echo "${a}sdf"  # 42sdf
echo "$asdf"  # prints nothing because there's no variable $asdf
```

Answer (score 3):

This functionality often is used to protect a variable name from surrounding characters.

```
$ var=foo
```

If we wish to concatenate a string at the end of `$var` We cannot do:

```
$ echo $varbar  

$
```

as this is trying to use a new variable `$varbar`.
Instead we need to enclose `var` in `{}` as:

```
$ echo ${var}bar
foobar
```